# How to inject photos to a Gatsby site?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have a Gatsby and Strapi photo blog and I want to have a home page that loads 10 pictures at a time until the user hits the bottom of the page, then load the next ten etc, so that the user isn't downloading all photos at once.

I'm using [useStaticQuery](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/use-static-query/) to load the images initially. However, that can only run at build time. Is there a way to make another graphQL call when the user hits the bottom of the page and add it to my state? Or is this the "static" part of a static site generator .

Alternatively, does making the graphQL call for all photo data make its way to the client device if I don't render it? Say if I just use React to render parts of the array at a time?

Below is my home page. I'm using [Karl Run's bottom scroll listener](https://github.com/karl-run/react-bottom-scroll-listener), and the Photos component renders the photos as a list.

```
const IndexLayout: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const [photosData, setPhotosData] = useState<InitialQueryType['allStrapiPhoto']>(getSiteMetaDataAndTenPhotos().allStrapiPhoto)

  const handleOnDocumentBottom = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('at bottom, make a call')

    // this throws an invalid hook error as getTenPhotos calls useStaticQuery
    let morePhotosData = getTenPhotos(photosData.edges.length)

    setPhotosData({ ...photosData, ...morePhotosData })
  }, [photosData])

 useBottomScrollListener(handleOnDocumentBottom)

  return (
    <LayoutRoot>
      <div className={styles.bigHomeContainer}>
        <div className={styles.titleContainer}>
          <h1 className={styles.indexHeading}>TayloredToTaylor's Wildlife Photos</h1>
        </div>
        <Photos photos={photosData} />
      </div>
    </LayoutRoot>
  )
}

export default IndexLayout
```

[Github Repo](https://github.com/nodes777/strapi-gatsby-typescript-blog/tree/limitTo10Recent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, queries are called in the build-time. However, one workaround that may work for you is to retrieve all photos at the beginning (build-time) and show them on-demand in groups of 10 triggered by time or by the user's scroll, etc. Adapting something like this to your use-case should work:

Fetch all photos with:

```
  const allPhotos=<InitialQueryType['allStrapiPhoto']>(getSiteMetaDataAndTenPhotos().allStrapiPhoto)
```

Set the current `currentIndex`:

```
const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex]= useState(0);
```

And ask them on-demand:

```
const morePhotosData = ()=>{
   let cloneOfAllPhotos= [...allPhotos];
   let newPhotos= cloneOfAllPhotos.splice(currentIndex, currentIndex + 10) // change 10 to your desired value
   
   setPhotosData(newPhotos);
   setCurrentIndex(currentIndex+10);
}
```

Basically, you are cloning the `allPhotos` (`let cloneOfAllPhotos= [...allPhotos]`) to manipulate that copy and splicing them with a dynamic index (`cloneOfAllPhotos.splice(currentIndex,currentIndex + 10)`) that is increasing by 10 in each trigger of `morePhotosData`.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Ferren! But does this mean that the client is always downloading all photos? I want to avoid sending a heavy payload unless the user requests all the data.

Comment: It's not that simple, you can lazy load the images or use `gatsby-image`, the images are fetched but not served until they are needed. If not, alternatively, you can use a native request to an external API to fetch the images and serve them on-demand.

Comment: ah I'm already using gatsby-image so it sounds like thats the way to go. thanks!